# how to create google maps marker with custom field values?

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I just placed a google map on my website following the instructions from google maps API: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/adding-a-google-map

Copying that example works perfectly but I would like to get the position of the marker depending on a custom field created in each post from WordPress

```
<div id="map"></div>
    <?php $lati = get_field( "gmapslat" ); ?>
    <?php $lat = get_field( "gmapslng" ); ?>
    <script>
        function initMap() {
            var lat = '<?php echo $lat; ?>';
            var lng = '<?php echo $lng; ?>';
            var uluru = {lat: lat, lng: lng};
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                zoom: 10,
                center: uluru
            });
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: uluru,
                map: map
            });
        }
    </script>

    <script async defer
        src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDPGx6I2w6hzEmQNR2IrRKlFC9oUT-COvs&callback=initMap">
    </script>

</div>
```

When do that the map just shows grey.

Comment: (A spelling checker might not point out missing full stops and subjects, but try using one, anyway.) (Welcome to SO - where salutations, pleas, TIAs are considered noise. Heed [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask))

Comment: What errors do you see in the javascript console?

Answer (score 0):

It seems there's a problem with your PHP variables. This PHP Variable **$lng** is not declared. So you are setting an undeclared PHP variable in Javascript variable **lng**.

I also noticed these lines:

```
<?php $lati = get_field( "gmapslat" ); ?>
<?php $lat = get_field( "gmapslng" ); ?>
```

Is this variable **$lat** value a longitude? If so, use **$lng** instead. Using meaningful names for variables would be helpful. Variable names must define the exact explanation of its content, regardless of programming language. Checking this blog **[15 Best Practices of Variable & Method Naming](http://codebuild.blogspot.com/2012/02/15-best-practices-of-variable-method.html)** might help.

Important: Use parseFloat() on each javascript variable width coordinates to return a floating point number. Else, it won't work and you'll just see a grey map. To learn more about definition and usage of parseFloat(), you can check **[JavaScript parseFloat() Function](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parsefloat.asp)**.

Below is a sample code using "-25.363, 131.044" as a sample coordinates returned by your **PHP get_field() function**:

```
<div id="map"></div>
<?php 
        function get_field($args) {
          switch ($args) {
            case 'gmapslat':
              return '-25.363';
            break;
            case 'gmapslng':
              return '131.044';
            break;  
          }
        }
      $lat = get_field('gmapslat');
      $lng = get_field('gmapslng');
?>

    <script>

      function initMap() {
        var lat = parseFloat("<?php echo $lat; ?>");
        var lng = parseFloat("<?php echo $lng; ?>");
        var myLatLng = {lat: lat , lng: lng};

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 4,
          center: myLatLng
        });

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: myLatLng,
          map: map,
          title: 'Hello World!'
        });
      }
    </script>
    <script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap">
    </script>
```

Hope it could help and happy coding!